# Array value to properties name javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, shortest

Is there a one-line way to transform array value to the properties name of an object?

Example:

```js
var arr = ['name', 'age', 'size'];
```

To

```js
{'name' :null, 'age':null, 'size':null}
```

Actually I'm processing like this:

```js
var arr = ['name', 'age', 'size'];
let obj = {};
arr.map(z => obj[z] = null);
```

I suppose that is the shortest way but I'm not sure.

Comment: You could use reduce instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reduce`:

```
arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  return Object.assign(prev, {[curr]: null})
}, {})
```

or you can one-line it if you want, but imo it looks worse then:

```
arr.reduce((prev, curr) => Object.assign(prev, {[curr]: null}), {})
```

Note, that `Object.assign` is a better way to code this, rather than using spread operator (`{... }`).

Spread operator creates a NEW object every loop. This can lead to big performance issues.

`Object.assign` on the other hand works on the first object.

Comment: Thank you for the assign details this will be the good answear

Comment: Didn't know `Object.assign` returned the target object, nice one!

Answer (score 2):

`reduce` could turn it into a one-liner:

```
var obj = arr.reduce((acc, curr)=> ({...acc, [curr]: null}),{})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method to convert an array to another type

```js
var arr = ["name", "age", "size"];

let output = arr.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  return {...accumulator, [current]: null}
}, {})

console.log(output);
```